# JSON and Java: I store a long. I want to get the long. But: "org.json.JSONException: JSONObject is not a long". What's wrong?

Tags: java, json, org.json

When I try to make the following (using org.json):

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.append("theLong", 1l);
Long theLong = jo.getLong("theLong");
```

I get the exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["theLong"] is not a long.
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[1]"
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Remark:
Also unnecessarily boxing the long in a long `jo.append("theLong", new Long(1l));` (to be sure that a `Long` is passed, not a `long`) wont help.

Comment: you should use `jo.put("theLong", 1l);`;   append is used to "Append values to the array under a key. If the key does not exist in the JSONObject, then the key is put in the JSONObject with its value being a JSONArray containing the value parameter. If the key was already associated with a JSONArray, then the value parameter is appended to it."

Comment: Thank you very much! If you want to post this as an answer, I would accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `jo.put("theLong", 1l);`

`append` is used to "Append values to the array under a key. If the key does not exist in the JSONObject, then the key is put in the JSONObject with its value being a JSONArray containing the value parameter. If the key was already associated with a JSONArray, then the value parameter is appended to it."